# How can we formulate an anti-knight Sudoku as an exact cover problem?

Tags: algorithms, constraint-satisfaction

Formulating standard Sudoku as an exact cover problem is easy and well documented. All of the constrained groups contain every digit which makes it natural to express the problem this way. [Wikipedia claims without citation that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover#Sudoku):

> Although other Sudoku variations have different numbers of rows, columns, numbers and/or different kinds of constraints, they all involve possibilities and constraint sets, and thus can be seen as exact hitting set problems.

How would one formulate other variants as exact cover problems with an incidence matrix? I'm focusing on the anti-knight variant, but with the goal of learning about expressing arbitrary variants.

The anti-knight Sudoku variant includes all of the standard rules, and additionally requires that no two squares which are a knight's move (in chess) apart may contain the same digit. I don't know how to approach this because a constraint between two squares cannot be expressed as requiring all digits to be present in some permutation. I can imagine a version of Algorithm X that solves this by removing additional rows by manual application of the anti-knight rule, but I believe Wikipedia is claiming this constraint should be expressible in the matrix alone without modifying the algorithm.

Is Wikipedia's claim that all variants can be expressed this way correct, and how would one approach the anti-knight example?

Comment: You're taking Wikipedia very literally. I don't think they meant your kind of variant.

Comment: That said, with the proper encoding, *everything* is an exact cover problem, that is, you can reduce SAT to an exact cover problem.

Comment: @Yuval-Filmus Hmm, it says "different kinds of constraints" and anti-knight is among the most common Sudoku variations, but perhaps that's not what it means. It is ununcited paragraph...

Comment: I have never heard of anti-knight constraints. So I would dispute your claim. I did see Sudokus with 3x3 squares replaced with other regions. I suspect that Wikipedia is referring ti such variants, and to variants with a larger number of digits.

Comment: @Yuval-Filmus Perhaps "among the most common" was an overstatement, but it's certainly reasonably common. That doesn't really matter, though. Taking another run at this this morning I've found that it's actually quite easy to solve this problem. I'll put in an answer later when I've confirmed my thinking.

Comment: The short version of the explanation is that it's tackled well by a common extension of exact cover where some columns are allowed to feature zero or one times in the solution. This is expressible by the standard algorithm by adding additional rows whose purpose is to fill the optional values if nothing else does.

Answer (score 1):

We start with the regular sudoku exact cover problem:

#### Sudoku Set Cover

- 729 sets, each `(row, col, num)` triple.

  - Each set contains 4 elements: `(row, col)`, `(row, num)`, `(col, num)`, `(box, num)` -- corresponding to the below.
- 324 elements:

  - 81 elements, each `(row, col)` pair.
  - 81 elements, each `(row, num)` pair.
  - 81 elements, each `(col, num)` pair.
  - 81 elements, each `(box, num)` pair.

This creates a 729 x 324 matrix with 2916 ones.

#### Anti-Knight Constraints

There are 152 non-redundant anti-knight moves (24 in 4 corner boxes, 38 in 4 edge boxes, and 56 in the middle box, all divided by 2 to avoid double-counting).

The anti-knight moves are like boxes that only contain two cells. However we only want to avoid an intersection, we don't care about covering all 1-9 nums. To allow this we add dummy sets which each contain a single element corresponding to a knight constraint. (This is the [extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover#Generalizations) described in the [comments](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/129399/how-can-we-formulate-an-anti-knight-sudoku-as-an-exact-cover-problem#comment271507_129399)).

- 1368 (9 * 152) new sets, each `(knight-move, num)` pair, each containing the 1 corresponding element.
- 1368 new elements, each `(knight-move, num)` pair.
- Each existing set `(row, col, num)` gets *up to* 8 more elements added which are the knight jumps with number `num` either starting or ending at that cell. Total is 2736 additional set members.

The final result is a 2097 x 1692 matrix with 7020 ones.

Comment: Just as an addendum, if you're using the DLX algorithm as your solver, Knuth's paper explains how to support "optional" rules using the example of the N-Queens problem. So you could extend that to antiknight/antiking/antiortho sudoku very easily.